# Is there any Xilinx OpenCL host-side implementation for ARM available?

Tags: opencl, embedded-linux, xilinx

I'm coming from a mostly Altera/Intel based FPGA background. Intel provides an OpenCL SDK that allows to translate OpenCL kernels to FPGA configurations. In case of SoCs that integrate an ARM, Intel also provides a host side driver implementation, allowing to invoke the kernels from within a Linux based application running on the ARM, very much just like it would be done with OpenCL executed on a GPU attached to the host.

Now I have a use-case where the hardware platform is a Xilinx Zynq SoC. I found out that Xilinx provides a HLS compiler that can compile the OpenCL kernel for usage in an FPGA as well. Those can then be attached to the ARM through Vivado. However I found no hint regarding a host side OpenCL Linux driver implementation for those Xilinx systems, all examples I found invoke the kernels through some very low-level mechanisms.

My question: Is there any Xilinx-supplied host implementation I overlooked or am I right that Xilinx does not supply any OpenCL host driver? Are there any reliable third party implementations of such a host driver?